# Deploying my project to azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I want to deploy my project to azure . and actually i tried most the tutorials and most of them old or not working with me ..

So this is the steps I made until deployed my project :

1- Created a custom web app + database (2gb).
2- changed the connection string in Web.Release.config

```
<add name="SmartBookLibraryModel1" connectionString="Server=tcp:q391yduiua.database.windows.net,1433;Database=smtebooksdb;User ID=Firasmsw@q391yduiua;Password={123456};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
```

3-Deployed the project as usual and selected the db connection to the db i created on azure .

4-Published it after I previewed the files .

Then it's started upload, after it finished I saw a new page runs out, and was my site. but can't login, register, use any function in controller... **after checking i noticed that the controller and other folders did not uploaded !!!**

And when i want to see my home page or any page that calling a controller i see this error : "**Error.
An error occurred while processing your request."**

So what i want please from someone have experience with deploying to help me with that , and advise me to the correct way.

**If someone** can just write to me a list of instruction here that i should do to deploy my site + my sql database.

**Note : I used code first from database + migration in my project and thanks**

Also here is the site to check it :
[My Site](http://smtebooks.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Hi .You trying to publish local database ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the files are deployed, the site is running. You do not need to upload the folders with source code. I guess you have a problem with your database create scripts. Have you tried to remove the database locally and the recreate it. You probably have the same error then. Make a backup before you do this.

Then fix your migrations to deploy the dbo.Book table and other missing tables, key and indexes.

Comment: how i can deploy the tables using migration?

Comment: Do you know how to do that , please because it's my graduation project and should be work tomorrow , else that i will get fail ... i left the deployment to the end because i thought it's easy and quick !!

Comment: Also after checking the problem with connection string . this is my default connection :     <add name="SmartBookLibraryModel1" connectionString="data source=FIRAS-JC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=SBL;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: what i should change to make it run perfectly ?

Comment: I think you have to read some documentation on how migrations work and than apply it to your project.